# Rails: Google login with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm using Devise & Omniauth on my rails 3.0.7 app, and I've already set up a functioning twitter and facebook logins. I just got Google Apps login working through omniauth with the following lines in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'
use OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleApps, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')

provider :openid, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
```

But this leads to a login with Google Apps. How do I just allow users to log in with their standard google accounts, not Google Apps (which is for corporates)? Is that even supported by Omniauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this as a [gem](https://github.com/fabn/google_authentication). If you're interested you can use the gem itself or explore its source code. It's pretty simple.

This is [the engine file](https://github.com/fabn/google_authentication/blob/develop/lib/google_authentication/engine.rb) which configures devise. To support standard google accounts in your code you need to specify the `:domain` option as pointed out [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

```
config.omniauth :google_apps, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :domain => 'gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer may not work in omniauth > 1.0.
It looks like the current way to do this is to include the gem for every strategy you are going to use.  You can find a list of strategies here:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies

One issue I ran into is that the new google api returns a callback url that is too long for webrick.  This can be worked around by running dev in thin or mongrel.